# creating a .pxd file for a python module

Tags: python, cython

One way of using cython, the Python to C compiler,
is to instead of rewriting your python code in Cython, just writing a .pxd file with the same name of your module where you declare the type of your variables, as explained in [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html)

Does anyone know a way to automate or semi-automate this process?

Answer (score 5):

What specifically are you trying to automate? Cython can take a python module and compile it down into C, but this only achieves modest speed increases. Most of the speed increase comes from providing type declarations. And that's really not something you can automate. You have to provide them one way or another to get best speed increase.

You can put the type declarations in the `.py` file itself. When run in the Python interpreter the type declarations have no effect. But when compiled, cython can use them to make certain optimisations. eg.

**some_module.py**

```
def myfunction(x, y=2):
    a = x-y
return a + x * y
```

**some_module.pxd**

```
cpdef int myfunction(int x, int y=*)
```

Can instead be written as:

(a) using decorators

```
@cython.locals(x=cython.int, y=cython.int, a=cython.int)
@cython.returns(cython.int)
def myfunction(x, y=2):
    a = x-y
    return a + x * y
```

Or, (b) using annotations

```
# cython: annotation_typing=True

def myfunction(x: {'ctype': 'int'}, y: {'ctype': 'int'}=2) -> {'ctype': 'int'}:
    a = x-y
    return a + x * y
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I haven't found a way to fully automate this but semi-automating -- which really needs minor effort to fully automate -- is available.

In the official `Cython` repository on github there's a script [`jedityper.py`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Tools/jedityper.py). This script, which has a dependency on [Jedi](http://jedi.jedidjah.ch/en/latest/), a static analyser for Python, takes in a `*.py` file and outputs a `*.py_typed.py` file with decorator annotations as mentioned in @Dunes answer.

Taking the code mentioned in the documentation you linked:

```
def myfunction(x, y=2):
    a = x-y
    return a + x * y

def _helper(a):
    return a + 1

class A:
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = b

    def foo(self, x):
        print x + _helper(1.0)
```

and passing it through `jedityper`, you'd get the following:

```
import cython
@cython.locals(a='long', y='long')
def myfunction(x, y=2):
    a = x-y
    return a + x * y

@cython.locals(a='double')
def _helper(a):
    return a + 1

class A:
    @cython.locals(b='long', self='object', a='long')
    def __init__(self, b=0):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = b

    @cython.locals(self='object')
    def foo(self, x):
        print x + _helper(1.0)
```

As you can see, this is half the job. Writing a little script that parses the function `def`s and `cython.locals` lines and performs some trivial matching shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I still think the augmenting .pxd file is more elegant. but this jedityper seem to be really interesting, and a big help.